# OpenID authentication error

Tags: authentication, openid

When I try to login to this site using my yahoo openid, it takes me to the yahoo site, I click "continue" meaning that i *want* to send my authentication details to stackoverflow.com and stackoverflow.com gives me the following error underneath the login text field:

Unable to log in with your OpenID provider:

failed to authenticate, returning Failed. Please ensure your identifier is correct and try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go to http://openid.yahoo.com/ and log in there. Then it will give you a URL that you can cut and paste into the login for stackoverflow that should work every time.

Answer (score 0):

I had that problem once before, clear you cache and cookies and try it again, it should resolve itself.